# How to fix error in step function (stepcACI): rep(no, length.out = len)

Tags: r

I got the following error running the stepcAIC function in a linear mixed effect model (lmer):

> *Fehler in rep(no, length.out = len) :
> attempt to replicate an object of type 'language'*

I don't understand what the error is saying. All the factors are declared as "factors" and all the other variables as "numeric". The storage.mode is "integer" for the factors and "double" for the other variables.

This is my model and the step function:

```r
biom_FULLO<-lmer((above_bio)~MUM_germ_time+MUM_num_seed+MUM_av_seed_mass+
          MUM_num_inf+MUM_above_bio+MUM_total_bio+MUM_inf_size+MUM_root_bio+
          MUM_CV_seed_mass+MUM_CV_SEM_per_inflor+MUM_CV_inflor_size+
          MUM_seed_weight+germ_date_year+germ_time+flow_start_date+
          height_3m+height_flow+num_inf+seed_gen+Early+
          Late+seed_gen:Early+seed_gen:Late+
          Early:Late+seed_gen:Early:Late+(1|ID_year), DT_gen_biom)

biom_step<-stepcAIC(biom_FULLO, direction = "backward", 
      trace = FALSE, data = DT_gen_biom)
```

Any idea anyone?

P.D.: traceback()

```
6: ifelse(wasGam, formula(modelInit$gam)[[2]], formula(modelInit)[[2]])
5: makeFormula(x, modelInit)
4: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
3: lapply(newSetup, function(x) makeFormula(x, modelInit))
2: calculateAllCAICs(newSetup = newSetup, modelInit = object, numCores = numCores, 
       data = data, calcNonOptimMod = calcNonOptimMod, nrmods = numberOfSavedModels, 
       ...)
1: stepcAIC(biom_FULLO, direction = "backward", trace = FALSE, data = DT_gen_biom)
```

Comment: Do you have an object called `no` in your environment?. If not, show us the result of `traceback()`

Comment: Thanks danlooo for the fast response! I had no object called "no", so I traced back:

Comment: Put this into your question formatted as code

Comment: Reproduce the error and do  traceback() and not  traceback. The output must have numbers at the beginning of a line

Comment: sorry! thought I did this :D hope that it is fine now!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the parenthesis of your response variable in the LHS of your formula:

```r
library(cAIC4)
#> Loading required package: lme4
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> Loading required package: stats4
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'nlme'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:lme4':
#> 
#>     lmList
library(lme4)

m1 <- lmer((Sepal.Length) ~ Sepal.Width + (1|Species), data = iris)
stepcAIC(m1)
#> Warning in nobars(formula(modelInit)) == formula(modelInit)[[2]]: longer object
#> length is not a multiple of shorter object length
#> Error in rep(no, length.out = len): attempt to replicate an object of type 'language'

m2 <- lmer(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + (1|Species), data = iris)
stepcAIC(m2)
#> $finalModel
#> Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
#> Formula: Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + (1 | Species)
#>    Data: iris
#> REML criterion at convergence: 194.6361
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
#>  Species  (Intercept) 1.010   
#>  Residual             0.438   
#> Number of obs: 150, groups:  Species, 3
#> Fixed Effects:
#> (Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
#>      3.4062       0.7972  
#> 
#> $additionalModels
#> NULL
#> 
#> $bestCAIC
#> [1] 184.0044
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: How the heck did you figure that out??

Comment: I've never seen someone writing `(y) ~ x` in a formula. Doing so, I was accidentally to reproduce your error. Typos are quite common, and their errors can be very weird.

Comment: fantastic!!! Worked!! thanks a lot :)

Comment: yeah it was still there from a former transformation... forgot to delete it. Did not know that it can create such a problem

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to report this to the package maintainers. (`maintainer("cAIC4")`)

Comment: It's not a fault of the package. You did not provide valid formula syntax.